# Storing YouTube references - URL or Video ID?

Tags: youtube

I'm working on a webapp where I need store references to YouTube videos in a database.

For each stored entry, I need to be able to use the YouTube reference to a): show a YouTube thumbnail for the referenced video, b): show the referenced video in an embeded YouTube video player.

What would be most beneficial in this case - store the full YouTube URL or just the video id part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just the video id from youtube is fine, I also save this info to a table and generate the thumb images using the URL http://img.youtube.com/vi/iGpYLmy7F3Q/0.jpg

Comment: 0.jpg isn't necessarily the highest quality thumbnail.  Most of the time there is an hqdefault.jpg, so a better URL would be http://img.youtube.com/vi/iGpYLmy7F3Q/hqdefault.jpg.  If using the YouTube Data API, they recommend using the reported height and width attribute values to select the thumbnail. ref: [Reference Guide: Data API Protocol - YouTube — Google Developers, media:thumbnail](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube_data_api_tag_media:thumbnail)